# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error Ubuntu 18.04 x86-64 target

Tags: 18.04, gcc

I get the following error when executing my binary test1:

```
   $ ./test1    
   bash: ./test1: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I checked that I have the 'x' right on this binary:

```
   $ ls -la test1
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 *** *** 5864 Apr  9 17:04 test1
```

I also verified that both my file and my ubuntu run on x86-64 target:

```
   $ file test1
   test1: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped
   $ uname -a
   Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020 x86_64     x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Finally, my gcc version is:

```
   $ gcc --version
   gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

Could you help please?

Comment: How exactly did you obtain `test1`? the message `ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable` suggests that it is an object code file not an executable file

Comment: That's it. The command gcc that I used was not good:
gcc -g -Wall -c test1.c -o test1

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command that you used

```
gcc -g -Wall -c test1.c -o test1
```

creates a binary object file, not an executable file. From `man gcc`:

> ```
>    When you invoke GCC, it normally does preprocessing, compilation,
>    assembly and linking.  The "overall options" allow you to stop this
>    process at an intermediate stage.  For example, the -c option says not
>    to run the linker.  Then the output consists of object files output by
>    the assembler.
> ```

To create an executable program, you need to allow `gcc` to proceed to the link phase by removing the `-c` option:

```
gcc -g -Wall test1.c -o test1
```